# surrogate for flask config.from_pyfile

Tags: python, flask

I want to extend an application which uses roughly this code:

```
app = Flask('app')
app.config.from_pyfile('default_config.py')
app.config.from_pyfile('local_config.py', silent=True)
```

There, the settings can be accessed using `app.config['value']` .
In my extension I only want to use the config files, without a Flask app and without creating a Flask object.

My only idea was:

```
import default_config as dc
import config as cc

vars_dc = [var for var in dir(dc) if not var.startswith('__')]
settings = {var: getattr(dc, var) for var in vars_dc}
vars_cc = [var for var in dir(cc) if not var.startswith('__')]
settings.update({var: getattr(cc, var) for var in vars_cc})
```

Which does not seem to be a good solution, as there are many pitfalls to consider (errors in config file etc. , so i would have to reimplement all exception handling and stuff)

Is there any module which has such functionality implemented?

*** EDIT ***

```
#default_config.py
HOST = 'myhostname'
PORT = 7453
DEBUG = False
MY_URLS = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but I believe this should work:

```
from importlib import import_module

app.config = import_module("default_config").__dict__
```

Answer (score 1):

What's stopping you doing it [the same way Flask does it](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/config.py#L110)?

Comment: I' d rather not copy any existing source code (or writing a new solution) if there is any other, as it would make my own module confusing (loading a config file seems being basic functionality, so anyone reading my source code would surely ask himself, why i am reimplementing it) . 
as `from py_file` is a class function, I would need to create a class instance to reuse it from flask module which I also do not want to. I do not see any other way to reuse it without reimplementing it

Comment: So you don't want to copy existing source code, and you don't want to write your own? Why not just `import default_config` and access your vars with `default_config.HOST`, etc?

Comment: Well copying existing code would mean redundancy, which would be a bad style.

I cannot access my vars with `default_config.HOST` etc as there might or might not be also a `config` file which can but does not need to overwrite any of the settings

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly but if you are talking about using the config in your extension code, you can use it directly as long as you have the `__init__` defined as:

```
class MyExtension(object):

def __init__(self, app=None):
    self.app = app
    if app is not None:
        self.init_app(app)

def init_app(self, app):
    # now you can use app.config
    app.config.get('HOST')
```

Comment: The point is that in this case I would need a `Flask(app)` object. I do not want to initialize a whole new object, I simply want to read the settings from the settings file into a dictionary

Comment: you don't need the Flask(app) object. You are passing the "app" as a parameter in those methods. You do app = Flask(__name__) only once in your actual application and not the extension code. See this one for an example https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt/blob/master/flask_bcrypt.py

Comment: Thanks :) . In fact I do not want to have a Flask app. 
The Application I am extending uses flask to serve a rendered html. I want to extend its functionality the way it exports the html automatically to a file and therefore I do not need to fire up a flask application. You might consider the whole application as two parts: First part is the one which renders the html and serves it with flask, the second one renders it and writes to a file or stdout. I just want the two parts to share the properties and to work side by side without influencing eachother

Comment: @ProfHase85: So your extension is really not dependent on Flask, and in fact not an extension but just an arbitrary Python library?

Comment: Exactly. I am just extending an already existing Flask project and I want to use it's configuration. I do not know why Flask has decided to use it's own config file format instead of using for example.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html